# Run Parent Javascript from iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, mouseover

[I have page (Red) with an iFrame on (whi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EjaE.png)te). Within the code of the iFrame, there is another iFrame containing another 2 pages (Green & Blue).

In the Red page, i have some Javascript that allows a hidden sidebar to appear when the mouse hovers on the right side of the screen (300px from right). This works fine, however if the user pulls the mouse away and the curser hovers over the red or green pages in the iFrame, the sidebar will not retract. However if the user retracts the curser into the red area (top and left) the sidebar retracts as expected. Im assuming that there is no code within the red and green pages telling the sidebar to retract when a mouseover occurs.

My problem is, i really suck at Javascript. How would I go about having the side bar retract regardless of where the mouse curser ends up? Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks

```js
 $(window).on('mousemove',function(e){
      
    if(e.pageX >= $(window).width() - 300 || e.target.id=='sidebar' ){
        $('#sidebar').css({'right':'0px'});
    }
     else{
     $('#sidebar').css({'right':'-300px'});
     }
    
});
```

Comment: *"if the user pulls the mouse away and the curser hovers over the red or green pages in the iFrame"*. I assume you mean blue and green?

Comment: that's is because you are listening the events on window and windows refers to your main window not the iframe. Attach events to your iframe

Comment: I have tried to add them into the iframe but have had no luck thus far, but then again, i really suck at Javascript so if you have an example that would really help.

Comment: test this... maybe it provides you an idea how it works... http://jsfiddle.net/nPdp7/453/

Answer (score -1):

Could you try to change the mousemove event to using mouse out and mouse in?

```
$(window).on('mousein',function(e){
    $('#sidebar').css({'right':'0px'});
}
$(window).on('mouseout',function(e){
    $('#sidebar').css({'right':'-300px'});
});
```

Also I would like to suggest maybe using a CSS based solution for this where instead using a `:hover` selector to show/hide the sidebar on mouse over

```css
.sidebar-container{
  width:300px;
  height:100%;
  background:#999;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
}

.sidebar-container .sidebar{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#465;
  position:absolute;
  left:-300px;
  top:0px;
  transition:all 0.5s;
}

.sidebar-container:hover .sidebar{
  left:0px
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-container">
  <div class="sidebar">Hi!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works however this would involve me re-engineering the entire page again which i'd like to try avoiding more work if possible. Isn't there something i can add into the iframe that runs the "close Sidebar" Javascript?

Comment: That is okay! Did you try changing to mousein/mouseout (The first part of my answer)? :]

Comment: It didn't unfortunately :( I almost feel like there should be something added after the 'else' in relation to the iframe...i just dont know the syntax for Javascript to even attempt to write it :(